# I cant find the solution :-\

Tags: c++

I have tried to write a short program that tells me where i should go for lunch. First in creates a "random" number based on the uptime of the pc and then takes the random number into to a switch function.

This what i have tried so far:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

long int x;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    long int x = 1 + (rand() % 10);

    switch (x)
    case 1:
    cout << "McDonalds" << endl;
    break;
case 2:
    cout << "Burger King" << endl;
    break;
case 3:
    cout << "Globus" << endl;
    break;
case 4:
    cout << "Plan B Burger" << endl;
    break;
case 5:
    cout << "Subway" << endl;
    break;
case 6:
    cout << "Chinese" << endl;
    break;
case 7:
    cout << "Döner" << endl;
    break;
case 8:
    cout << "Pizzeria" << endl;
    break;
case 9:
    cout << "Zenger" << endl;
    break;
}
```

But it doesn't print anything on the console.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Well, before you can expect your program to print anything you have to fix the compiler errors: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58430aaa96f7f629 How to fix it is pretty clearly told there IMO.

Comment: There are no errors. and thanks for welcoming me :-)

Comment: Ok, foud them on the website. my programm doesnt show them. (code::blocks)

Comment: @coderredoc is correct you are missing {} in your switch

Comment: Your compiler should have issued an error about that.

Comment: Please fix your title. It should describe the question. Remember that every post here should be able to help others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`switch(){..}`..correct syntax please.

Hope you have good lunch but before that try to check the syntax of `switch`

Comment: This explains why the formatting fix did not work..